# Full screen notifications unwantedly triggering keyguard

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, sdk, keyguard

I'm making an app that shows full-screen notifications when the device is locked.

Expected behavior: when a notification is launched, the activity shows over the lock screen **without prompting the user to unlock the device**. It should be the same as an alarm clock notification, just without waking up the screen.

Code: in my onCreate() I'm calling:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
        setShowWhenLocked(true)
        val keyguardManager = getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
        keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this,null)
             
    } else {
        this.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD)
        this.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED)
    }
```

Problem: in some devices (e.g. Pixel 6 API 31), when the full-screen intent is launched, the keyguard is shown on top of my activity asking the user to enter their credentials. If I dismiss the keyguard, my activity remains on the screen (so the device didn't have to be unlocked in the first place!). What I want to avoid is having the keyguard show and having to dismiss it! In other devices (e.g. old Huawei tablet, API 27), the full-screen intent launches smoothly without requesting to unlock the device, which is what I want.

I tried simply not calling keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(). This solves the issue on my Pixel 6 API 31 (which now works like the Huawei API 27 did before). But now the Huawei API 27 does not launch the full-screen intent at all.

I have no idea if this is an API thing or a device/ROM-specific thing. I checked the documentation but didn't find anything helpful. Has anyone come across this issue before? Any ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, In pixel 4a if I use requestDismissKeyguard, the PIN input screen is displayed and if I don't use requestDismissKeyguard, still the view is not displayed.

I need to input the PIN to see the full-screen Intent, Have you found any solution?

Comment: almost year later: any updates on that topic?